# Remove the height limit on wordpress 3.4.2

Tags: images, limit

I have problems when insert images on my pages.

I have a image of  1113 × 731 and I upload it to my wordpress, when I go to Add Object popup, the Full size of the image mode is of: 950 x 342.

When I upload a larger sized image this always limit the height to 342, Why?

I tried deleting the width/height html attribute from the image, but the URL image looks like this "http://mywordpress.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/image-950x342.jpg"

This always modify the height to 342, but I cant find these option on any place.

[image: example image]

Thanks for the help.

Title edited. Sorry Wordpress 3.4.2

This a example code when I insert a image in one of my pages:

```
<a href="http://todogangas.net/telefonia/movil/" rel="attachment wp-att-1712"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1712" title="MOVIL" src="http://todogangas.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/MOVIL-572x342.jpg" alt="" width="572" height="342" /></a>
```

How you can see, the image used in the src is a little version that create wordpress, i want this use the real size url: http://todogangas.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/MOVIL.jpg

Comment: WordPress 3.2 maybe?

Comment: It would help a lot if you [switch your admin UI language](https://github.com/wecodemore/wcm_lang_switch) to English for screenshots. As most people here, I am not able to read Spanish (or Portuguese?).

Comment: You are missing out on some great wordpress features if you are still using 3.2.

Comment: Use add_image_size function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no height limit in WordPress, however your theme may have set the Content Width to 950, so the limit is there on the width in the theme. This limit prevents you from inserting an image wider than the available space for it on the page.